# How to concatenate multiple ranges within a Match function

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I have a list of values that I would like to match against the combination of multiple ranges.

So, for example, my ranges are A1:A100 and B1:B100.

Instead of concatenating A with B in a new column C, i.e.

```
CONCAT(A1,B1)...CONCAT(A100,B100)
```

and then matching my value against that new column - I would like to do something like this:

```
MATCH(value,CONCATENATE(A1:B100),0)
```

And copy this down a column near my list of values.

I have a feeling this can be done with some sort of array formula...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes as an array formula:

```
=MATCH(value,$A$1:$A$100 & $B$1:$B$100,0)
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

Though they may seem similar in approach they are not.  CONCATENATE will return a string not an array to the `MATCH` with all 200 values in one long string.  Where the above will return 100 values, each row concatenated, as an array which can be used to search.

One further note, If performance becomes a issue, Array formulas are inherently slower, adding the helper column and using a regular `MATCH` will improve the responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, basically you just need to concatenate it yourself using &

```
=MATCH(D1,A1:A10&B1:B10,0)
```

D1 is the value you're trying to look for.

This is an array, so remember to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when you input it.